# Is it possible to highlight different characters in a HTML input element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an input that contains a logical expression e.g. a user can type 'A' AND 'B', 'A' AND ('B' OR 'C'), etc.  The expressions can get as complex as the user likes so I would like to add a brace matching feature that will highlight the close brace of the open brace the cursor is currently on in yellow, like it's done in various IDEs.

I've seen various examples of highlighting all the text in the input but haven't come across anything to highlight specific characters, and have also read that you can only apply one style to an element.  I'm kind of lost on how to go about this.

Comment: Only way to do such highlighting is with html elements and inputs only contain text. Might try one of the various code editors that are used in web pages. Codemirror, ace, monaco etc

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, unfortunately, no.

You need either to find a ready-made UI component for that or wrap up your own. That, on the other hand, is completely possible.

Comment: What do you mean wrap my own?  I could do that if I had some direction on where to start.  Thanks.

Comment: Writing an own highlighting editor component is not an easy task, but the ingredients include focusability (track focus by a focusable html element), keyboard input (set up a keyboard listener), transforming raw text input to a intermediary model and further to `<span>`-tagged html plus CSS to style the spans.